# replacing string is not working for lines having '&' character

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I am working on manipulating a string/line which is read from file "A.txt" and writing it to a new file "B.txt"

Here in the file A if the line contains '&' character the string replace is not working.

```
**for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type "%%F"') do (
set str=%%a
set filename=abc
set findStr=!filename!.
echo !findStr!
set replaceStr=folder1\!filename!\!filename!.
echo !replaceStr!
call set str=%%str:!findStr!=!replaceStr!%%**
)
```

Here for lines which are not having '&' the string replace works perfectly. Only when line contain the special character it is not working.

Please help me in understanding the issue here.

Note this is not the full script.

Comment: btw you should not use cmd commands for variable names: `findStr`

Comment: The ampersand is used by cmd.exe as a delimiter.  It is the equivalent of hitting return between commands. For example:  "dir %temp% > result.txt & result.txt" will dump the contents of the %temp% folder into a file called result.txt  AND then open it in whatever program you have associated with .TXT files.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (assuming that you already have delayed expansion enabled):

```
(for /f "delims=" %%a in (C:\path\to\A.txt) do (
  set "str=%%a"
  set "filename=abc"
  set "srch=!filename!."
  >&3 echo !srch!
  set "repl=folder1\!filename!\!filename!."
  >&3 echo !repl!
  call set "str=%%str:!srch!=!repl!%%"
  echo !str!
)) > C:\path\to\B.txt
```